# How do I insert a tag that holds the text of an older tag in xml using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

I want to insert s tags inside a tag that already exists and move the text of the older tag inside the s tag. For example, if my XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <name>Light and dark</name>
    <address>
        <sector>142</sector>
        <location>Noida</location>
    </address>
</root>
```

I want it to be like this (check the name tag):

```
<root>
    <name>
        <s>Light and dark</s>
    </name>
    <address>
        <sector>142</sector>
        <location>Noida</location>
    </address>
</root>
```

I tried using ET.SubElement but it doesn't give me the same result.

Comment: It is much better to use **XSLT** for such tasks. If you are open to do that, I can show how.

Comment: Sure, I don't mind using XSLT. Please do.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a sub-element in the XML using ElementTree XML API, append the new element then set it with the text value of the parent element.

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
 <root>
    <name>Light and dark</name>
    <address>
       <sector>142</sector>
       <location>Noida</location>
    </address>
 </root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

# 1. find name element in document
name = root.find('name')

# 2. get text value and reset the element
text = name.text
name.clear()

# 3. create new element s and set text
elt = ET.SubElement(name, "s")
elt.text = text

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

To process multiple elements, add a loop around steps 1-3:

```
for child in root.findall('name'):
    text = child.text
    child.clear()
    elt = ET.SubElement(child, "s")
    elt.text = text
```

**Output:**

```
<root>
   <name><s>Light and dark</s></name>
   <address>
    <sector>142</sector>
    <location>Noida</location>
   </address>
 </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

It it much better to use XSLT for such tasks.

XSLT has so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <name>Light and dark</name>
    <address>
        <sector>142</sector>
        <location>Noida</location>
    </address>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <s>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </s>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <name>
    <s>Light and dark</s>
  </name>
  <address>
    <sector>142</sector>
    <location>Noida</location>
  </address>
</root>
```